# Comment écrit-on communément « le rapport qualité-prix » ?

Tags: ordre-des-mots, ponctuation

Je dis, par exemple, « pour le rapport qualité-prix, on repassera » lorsque je me fais un resto, seulement pour constater qu’étant donné le prix, la qualité n’est pas au rendez-vous.

Je me demande si on a la latitude de mettre les deux noms « qualité » et « prix » l’un devant l’autre dans l'ordre souhaité ?

> « le rapport **qualité-prix** » =? « le rapport **prix-qualité** »

À propos, quel signe de ponctuation convient le mieux pour relier les deux noms : un trait d'union ou une barre oblique ? Ou bien peut-on s’en passer ?

> « le rapport **qualité/prix** »
>
> « le rapport **qualité prix** »

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est bien l'expression "rapport qualité-prix" qui s'utilise couramment. On n'utilise jamais "rapport prix-qualité".

On l'écrit avec un trait d'union ([TLFI](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/qualit%C3%A9-prix)) mais la barre oblique est acceptable ("rapport qualité/prix").